# How to use TouchableWithoutFeedback's props according to situation

Tags: react-native

I use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` as a button. But when I press the button I want it do 'A'.  When I do a long press of the button, I want it do 'B'. How do I can do this?

```react
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={() => console.warn('OnPressIN')} onLongPress={() => console.warn('OnLongPress')}>
    <Image source={require('../Images/add2.png')} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

What is happening is that when I do a long press, it gives me `OnPressIN`, and `OnLongPress`. but I want just `OnLongPress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onPressOut` with a state

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPressIn={() => this.setState({buttonPress: 'short'})}
  onLongPress={() => this.setState({buttonPress: 'long'})}
  onPressOut={() => {
    const {buttonPress} = this.state;
    if(buttonPress === 'short') {
      //do 'A'
    } else if (buttonPress === 'long') {
      //do 'B'
    }
    this.setState({buttonPress: 'none'});
  }}
>
```